# I want to create a random sample of length n from a normal multivariate distribution

Tags: r, self-study, multivariate-normal-distribution, bivariate

I have a problem in understanding this question, especially this part:

"generate a random sample of length n from a normal multivariate"

This is what I have done using the R package mvtnorm:

```
my_function <- function(n=1,k){
mean = rep(0,k)
sigma = diag(length(mean))
rmvnorm(n, mean, sigma,method=c("eigen", "svd", "chol"), pre0.9_9994 = FALSE)}
```

my_function(3)

This way the output of my function is, in this example, a vector of three numbers which in my mind is A sample of length 3. Is this correct? Is there another way to do this?

I am asking this question because I have to do the same without using the library rmvnorm and with a normal bivariate.

I just managed to write the density function:

```
dbivnorm <- function(x,y,mux=0,muy=0,sigmax=1,sigmay=1,rho=0){
  (2*pi)^(-1) * ((1-rho^2)*sigmax^2*sigmay^2)^(-.5) *
    exp( -((x-mux)^2/(sigmax^2) -2*rho*((x-mux)/sigmax *(y-muy)/sigmay) +
             (y-muy)^2/(sigmay^2))/(2*(1-rho^2)) )
}
```

But now I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: This is a sample of length one (1) and dimension three (3).

Comment: Ok, how do I get a sample of length n, with let's say n = 3 using rmvnorm?

Comment: Its manual page explains how.  You will figure it out quickly enough by running `rmvnorm` a few times with different argument values.  Since (for some reason) you don't want to use `rmvnorm`, could you please be specific about what tools or techniques you *are* willing to employ?  If the reason for not using the solution available to you is educational, then please tag your post with [tag:self-study].

Comment: @whuber: sorry, I typed my answer while you were typing your comment!

Answer (score 3):

Usually, a good starting point to understand how to run an R function is to read [the attached documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mvtnorm/mvtnorm.pdf):

[image: From mvtnorm package documentation, functions dmvnorm and rmvnorm]

which also contains an example as an illustration

[image]

where the entry `n` in `rmvnorm(n,mean,sigma)` is the number of elements in the random sample, while `mean` is the mean vector and `sigma` is the variance-covariance matrix.

Comment: Yes, I read that too but I have a doubt on my output: let's say I run rmvnorm(5,mean = rep(0,5), diag(length(mean))) This gives me a 5x5 matrix, but I just want the one random sample of length n, to me this seems 5 random samples of length 5. What am I not getting?

Comment: If $n=5$ and $k=5$, this is a correct outcome of $5$ realisations of a $5$-dimensional random vector.

Comment: In `R`, a matrix and an array of columns are identical concepts.

Answer (score 2):

Are you allowed to use a package that provides you with independent normal distributed RVs? If not, the Box-Muller method (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%E2%80%93Muller_transform) could be used for that.

Given that you have n independent normal distributed random variables, using the cholesky decomposition $L^\top L = \Sigma$ (for the wanted covariance matrix $\Sigma$) and multiplying $L$ by the vector of independent normal RVs gives you a multivariate normal distributed random variable with covariance $\Sigma$.

Comment: Mmm, could you be a bit more specific on the first part of my questions? I mean, is what I did right for generating a random sample of length n from a normal multivariate? Because for that part I am allowed to use the package.

Comment: I'm very unsure what you are doing in your first part, especially the relation between 'my_function' and 'using_rmvnorm'. Normally, simply 'rmvnorm(rep(0,k),diag(k))' should work.

Comment: Yeah, I overcomplicated that, plus using_rmvnorm should just be my_function. Anyway, I have still another question. Given that I have the density function for the bivariate distribution, can't I just use rand() two times to get two values for x and y and then compute dbivnorm(x,y)?